# Using Internet Explorer, from the UI of a website is it possible to view the Javascript that is behind certain functionality

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, web-developer-toolbar

I know a small amount of web development but not enough to make it a career. I am working for an organization that is restricted to using internet explorer and one of the main sites that we use is constantly undergoing changes and always has bugs.

I'd like to see if I can try to see some of the code behind the bugs sometimes.  When I use developer tools on the site, I can see that there are about 20 or more JavaScript files downloaded.  Each file is a few hundred to a few thousand lines long.   Is there any type of tool that I can use in Internet Explorer browser tools that can show me what JavaScript is being executed when actions happen on the webpage?

e.g.: I click a button and a form appears.  I then click a button on that form and a [snackbar](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_snackbar.asp) appears, but it always appears in random places.  Is there any way I can see the JavaScript that was executed to display the snackbar, rather than search line by line in the JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer is yes, but for more complicated sites it will be a painful experience. Without concrete knowledge of the javascript framework/library used it will often be near impossible.

Having the sourcecode for the website would help greatly. When the website has minified javascript it's pretty much a must.

Sometimes an element like a button will have an `onclick` attribute which makes a function call. Other time some function is attached to an element from javascript by addressing it by it's id etc.

Searching through the scripts using the F12 tools in Internet Explorer is very limited.

You can of course download some of the javascript files so you can browse them in a text/code editor. They may improve you ability to search etc.

If you can find some entry point you could use breakpoints with the debugger and step through to see what happens and what gets called.